# How do we get WebRTC to work with a VPN (have tried TURN solution)

Tags: webrtc, vpn

Our WebRTC app works in every environment until one user turns on a VPN.

The error we're getting is a failed ICE candidate.

We have tried leveraging TURNs along with STUNs, both public and private, still no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is your TURN server accessiable over TCP? In your ICE Servers list you should have two entries `turn:turn-server.com?protocol=tcp` and `turns:turn-server.com?protocol=tcp`. If you don't specify the protocol it will use UDP.

VPNs cause a few different issues with WebRTC. If it is connectivity there isn't much you can do. I have seen a few VPNs that by default have a very low MTU, it may be configurable.

Comment: thank you for the response, we've already tried this.

Our WebRTC servers work on a TCP & UDP protocol.

Comment: Connectivity is not really the issue we're facing, although I could see how that might be an issue.  Speed is higher than 10 MBPS even with the VPN.